# Elworthy’s 1982 “Stochastic Differential Equations on Manifolds” - relevant?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

In 1982, D. Elworthy published “Stochastic Differential Equations on Manifolds”. Apparently, this was quite a seminal book in the field of stochastic DE’s/processes on manifolds. Is this reference still relevant/didactic? If not, what
would you say is a good update?